# run code after the sharepoint page is loaded

Tags: web-services, web-part-page

I have the below code in CEWP and I l like that function runs after when the SharePoint site elements are loaded:

---

```
<html> 
<head> 

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

go ()

function go() {

...

}


</script>  
</head> 
</html>
```

Comment: Is that a JavaScript function? You can use `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push` as given [_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames](http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/10/05/_spbodyonloadfunctionnames-in-sharepoint-vs-jquerys-document-ready/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery this function just should be loaded in

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{  
// Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is the link to definition

Hope it helps,

Andrew